# Dereferencing pointer in CUDA C

Tags: c, pointers, cuda

I am a novice C programmer and was a bit confused about this segmentation fault. I have worked with pointers before and this doesn't make sense. This code is being done on an NVIDIA GPU but I am not using any of the CUDA API functions yet (commented them out to isolate the error).

I get the error when de-referencing the pointer *mu on the GPU (see code below) in the function calibrate. That is, the error is a segmentation fault.

My host code is:

```
/******************************************************************************
 *cr
 *cr
 ******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "kernel.cu"
#include "support.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Timer timer;
    cudaError_t cuda_ret;

    // Initialize host variables ----------------------------------------------

    printf("\nSetting up the problem...\n"); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    double* A_h, *T_h, *Delta_h, *E_h, *p_h, *p2_h, *D_h, *Times_h, *ones_h; 
    double* A_d, *T_d, *Delta_d, *E_d, *p_d, *p2_d, *D_d, *Times_d, *ones_d, *temp_1, *temp_2; 
    double* mu_h, *alpha_h, *omega_h;
    double* mu_d, *alpha_d, *omega_d;
    int N;
    unsigned int mat_size, vec_size;

    // Import data
    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];   
    unsigned int count=0;
    double d;

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("AAPL_data.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
    }
    while(fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL)
        ++count;    

    // Stick with a limited subset of the data for now
    N = 2000;

    fclose(fp); 
    printf("Count is %u \n",count);     

    mat_size = N*N;
    vec_size = N;

    dim3 dim_grid, dim_block;

    // Fill matrices with 0's
    A_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { A_h[i] = 0; }

    T_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { T_h[i] = 0; }

    Delta_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { Delta_h[i] = 0; }

    E_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { E_h[i] = 0; }

    p_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*mat_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < mat_size; ++i) { p_h[i] = 0; }

    // Fill vectors with 0's, except the 1's vector
    p2_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { p2_h[i] = 0; }

    Times_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { Times_h[i] = 0; }

    D_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { D_h[i] = 0; }

    ones_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double)*vec_size );
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) { ones_h[i] = 0; }

    // Start constants as zero
    mu_h    = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    alpha_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    omega_h = (double*) malloc( sizeof(double));
    *mu_h = 0;
    *alpha_h = 0;
    *omega_h = 0;

    // Import data
    count=0;

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("AAPL_data.txt","r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
    }       
    while(fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL)
    {
        sscanf(str, "%lf", &d);
        if(count < vec_size)
            Times_h[count] = d;
        ++count;
    }       
    fclose(fp); 


    /*printf("TIMES VECTOR: \n");   
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec_size; ++i) 
    { 
        printf("TIMES_H[ %u ] is ",i);
        printf("%f \n", Times_h[i]);
    }*/

    printf("Count is %u \n",count);     
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Allocate device variables ----------------------------------------------

    printf("Allocating device variables..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    cudaMalloc((void**) &A_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix A  
    cudaMalloc((void**) &T_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix T  
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Delta_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                 // Create device variable for matrix Delta
    cudaMalloc((void**) &E_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix E
    cudaMalloc((void**) &p_d, mat_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for matrix p
    cudaMalloc((void**) &p2_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                    // Create device variable for vector p2
    cudaMalloc((void**) &D_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                     // Create device variable for vector D
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Times_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                 // Create device variable for vector Times
    cudaMalloc((void**) &ones_d, vec_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for vector ones
    cudaMalloc((void**) &mu_d, sizeof(double));                             // Create device variable for constant mu
    cudaMalloc((void**) &alpha_d, sizeof(double));                          // Create device variable for constant alpha
    cudaMalloc((void**) &omega_d, sizeof(double));                          // Create device variable for constant omega
    cudaMalloc((void**) &temp_1, vec_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for constant omega
    cudaMalloc((void**) &temp_2, mat_size*sizeof(double));                  // Create device variable for constant omega

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Copy host variables to device ------------------------------------------

    printf("Copying data from host to device..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    cudaMemcpy(A_d,A_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(T_d,T_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(Delta_d,Delta_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(E_d,E_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(p_d,p_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(p2_d,p2_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);          // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(D_d,D_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);            // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(ones_d,ones_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);      // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(Times_d,Times_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);    // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(mu_d,mu_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);                   // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_d,alpha_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);             // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(omega_d,omega_h,sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);             // Copy from host var to device var

    cudaMemcpy(temp_1,D_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);         // Copy from host var to device var
    cudaMemcpy(temp_2,A_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);         // Copy from host var to device var


    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Launch kernel using standard sgemm interface ---------------------------
    printf("Launching kernel..."); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);

    int MAX_ITER = 100;
    double TOL = .001;

    calibrate(vec_size,mu_d, alpha_d, omega_d, A_d, T_d, Delta_d, E_d, p_d, p2_d, D_d, ones_d, Times_d, 
        MAX_ITER, TOL, temp_1, temp_2);


    //tiledSgemm('N', 'N', matArow, matBcol, matBrow, 1.0f, \
    //  A_d, matArow, B_d, matBrow, 0.0f, C_d, matBrow); // A1_d, B1_d);

    cuda_ret = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess) FATAL("Unable to launch kernel");
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));

    // Copy device variables from host ----------------------------------------

    printf("Copying data from device to host...\n"); fflush(stdout);
    startTime(&timer);


    cudaMemcpy(mu_h,mu_d,sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);        // Copy from device var to host var
    cudaMemcpy(alpha_h,alpha_d,sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  // Copy from device var to host var
    cudaMemcpy(omega_h,omega_d,sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  // Copy from device var to host var

    printf("mu is %f: \n",mu_h);
    printf("alpha is %f: \n",alpha_h);
    printf("omega is %f: \n",omega_h);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    stopTime(&timer); printf("%f s\n", elapsedTime(timer));


    // Free memory ------------------------------------------------------------

    free(A_h);
    free(T_h);
    free(Delta_h);
    free(E_h);
    free(p_h);
    free(p2_h);
    free(D_h);
    free(ones_h);
    free(Times_h);
    free(mu_h);
    free(alpha_h);
    free(omega_h);

    cudaFree(A_d);
    cudaFree(T_d);
    cudaFree(Delta_d);
    cudaFree(E_d);
    cudaFree(p_d);
    cudaFree(p2_d);
    cudaFree(D_d);
    cudaFree(ones_d);
    cudaFree(Times_d);
    cudaFree(mu_d);
    cudaFree(alpha_d);
    cudaFree(omega_d);

    return 0;
}
```

The Kernel code on the GPU is:

```
/*****************************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>

#define TILE_SIZE 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

__global__ void mysgemm(int m, int n, int k, const double *A, const double *B, double* C) {

    __shared__ float ds_A[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];
    __shared__ float ds_B[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];

    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    int row = (by*TILE_SIZE+ty);//%m;
    int col = (bx*TILE_SIZE+tx);//%n;
    float pvalue = 0;


    for(int i=0;i<(k-1)/TILE_SIZE+1;++i)
    {
        if((i*TILE_SIZE +tx < k) && (row < m))
            ds_A[ty][tx] = A[row*k+i*TILE_SIZE+tx];
        else ds_A[ty][tx] = 0;

        if((i*TILE_SIZE+ty < k) && (col < n)) 
            ds_B[ty][tx] = B[(i*TILE_SIZE+ty)*n+col];       // Load data into shared memory
        else ds_B[ty][tx] = 0;

        __syncthreads();

        if(row < m && col < n)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<TILE_SIZE;++j)
            {
                //if(j < k)
                    pvalue += ds_A[ty][j]*ds_B[j][tx];
            }
            }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if(row < m && col < n)
        C[row*n+col] = pvalue;
}

// Kernel to multiply each element in A by the corresponding element in B and store 
// the result to the corresponding element in C. All vectors should be of length m
__global__ void elem_mul(int m, const double *A, const double *B, double* C) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 
    if(i < m)
        C[i] = A[i]*B[i];
}

// Kernel for parallel sum
__global__ void reduction(double *out, double *in, unsigned size)
{
    __shared__ float partialSum[2*BLOCK_SIZE];
    unsigned int t = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int start = 2*blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    if(start + t >= size)
        partialSum[t] = 0;
    else partialSum[t] = in[start+t];

    if(start + blockDim.x+t>= size)
        partialSum[blockDim.x+t] = 0;
    else partialSum[blockDim.x+t] = in[start + blockDim.x+t];

    for(unsigned int stride = 1; stride <=blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        if(t % stride ==0)
            partialSum[2*t]+=partialSum[2*t+stride];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    out[blockIdx.x] = partialSum[0];
}

// Uses several kernels to compute the inner product of A and B
void inner_product(double *out, int m, const double *A, const double* B, double* temp)
{
    dim3    dimGrid((m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(m-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    elem_mul<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(m,A,B,temp);
    reduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(out,temp,m);        
}

// Kernel to multiply each element in the matrix out in the following manner:
// out(i,j) = in(i) - in(j)
__global__ void fill(int m, const double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y;    
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;

    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 
    int j = ty+by*blockDim.y; 

    if((i < m) && (j < m))
        out[i*m+j] = in[i]-in[j];
}

// Kernel to fill the matrix out with the formula out(i,j) = exp(-omega*T(i.j))
__global__ void fill_E(int m, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m)
        out[i] = exp(-coeff * in[i]);
}

// Kernel for scalar multiplication for an mxk matirx and a coefficient coeff
__global__ void scal_mul(int m, int k, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m*k)
        out[i] = coeff * in[i];
}

// Kernel for scalar multiplication for an mxk matirx and a coefficient coeff
__global__ void scal_add(int m, int k, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m*k)
        out[i] = coeff + in[i];
}

// Kernel to update vector p2
__global__ void update_p2(int m, double coeff, double *in, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    if(i < m)
        out[i] = coeff/in[i];
}

// Kernel to update matrix p
__global__ void update_p(int m, double* p2, double *denom, double *num, double *out) 
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;       
    int i = tx+bx*blockDim.x; 

    // loop through columns j
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
    {
        if(i == j)
            out[i*m + j] = p2[i];
        else if(i < m)
            out[i*m + j] = num[i*m+j]/denom[i];
    }
}


/*****************************************************************************************/
// int size:  length of the Time-series vectors. Also the number of rows and columns in input matrices
// double mu:       One of three parameters calibrated
// double alpha:    One of three parameters calibrated
// double omega:    One of three parameters calibrated
// double* A:       A matrix filled out and used to calibrate
// double* T:       A distance matrix T(i,j) = Times[i]-Times[j]
// double* Delta:   A dissimilarity matrix Delta(i,j) = 1 if i > j, 0 otherwise
// double* E:       A matrix filled out and used to calibrate--E(i,j) = exp(-omega*T(i,j))
// double* p:       A probability matrix of cross excitations
// double* p2:      A vector of self-excitation probabilities
// double* ones:    A (size x 1) vector of 1's used in inner products and identity transformations
// double* Times:   A (size x 1) vector of time series data to be calibrated
// int MAX_ITER:    The maximum number of iterations allowed in the calibration
// double* TOL:     The error tolerance or accuracy allowed in the calibration
// double* temp_1:  A (size x 1) temporary vector used in intermediate calculations 
// double* temp_2:  A temporary matrix used in intermediate calculations
/*****************************************************************************************/
void calibrate(int size, double *mu, double *alpha, double *omega, double *A, double *T, double *Delta, double *E, double *p, double *p2, double *D, double* ones, double *Times, int MAX_ITER, double TOL, double* temp_1, double* temp_2)
{   

    //1) (a) Perform inner product to start initial values of mu, alpha, and omega
    *mu = .11; // ERROR IS HERE!!
    /*
    inner_product(mu, size, Times, ones, temp_1);

    double a = *(mu);
    a = a/size;
    *mu = .11;

    /*  
    /size;
    *alpha =  *mu;
    *omega =  *mu;


    double mu_t = 0;
    double alpha_t = 0;
    double omega_t = 0;
    double err = 0;
    int ctr = 0;

    //1) (b) Fill out matrix T of time differences
    dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
    dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
    fill<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size, Times, T); 


    while(ctr < MAX_ITER && err < TOL)
    {
        // 2) Fill out matrix E
        dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
        dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
        fill_E<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size, omega, T, E);

        // 3) Update matrix A
        dim3    dimGrid((size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,(size-1)/BLOCK_SIZE+1,1);
        dim3    dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE,1);
        scal_mult<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, alpha, delta, A);
        scal_mult<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, omega, A, A);

        dim3    dimGrid((n-1)/TILE_SIZE+1,(m-1)/TILE_SIZE+1,1);
        dim3    dimBlock(TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,1);
        mysgemm<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size,size,A,E,A)


        // 4) Update matrix D 
        mysgemm<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size,1,A,ones,D);
        scal_add<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,size, mu, D, D);

        // 5) Update matrix p and vector p2
        update_p2<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,mu, D, p2);
        update_p<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(size,p2, D, A, p);

        // 6) Update parameters mu, alpha, omega
        inner_product(mu_t, size, p2, ones, temp_1);
        mu_t /=Times[size-1];

        reduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(alpha_t,p,size*size);
        alpha_t/= size;

        // Treat T and p as very long vectors and calculate the inner product
        inner_product(omega_t, size*size, T, p, temp_2);
        omega_t = alpha_t/omega_t;

        // 7) Update error
        ctr++;
        err = (mu - mu_t)*(mu - mu_t) + (alpha-alpha_t)*(alpha-alpha_t) + (omega-omega_t)*(omega-omega_t);
        mu = mu_t;
        alpha = alpha_t;
        omega = omega_t;

        cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
        if(error != cudaSuccess)
        {
            printf("CUDA error: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(error));
            exit(-1);
        }       
    }
    */
}
```

However, I think 99% of this code isn't relevant to the issue (I use nothing from "support.h" at the moment. Basically, I get an error de-referencing the pointer on the GPU, even though it is presumably not null. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked it's not null?  If you're getting an error de-referencing a pointer, chances are it's not null or it hasn't been initialized correctly.

Comment: Did you try debugging? your code is rather long, can you try cutting it down to pin-point the error.

Comment: @Steve I am pretty sure it's not null. I was able to assign the de-referenced value to a temporary double a. That is, double a = *mu worked. The other way isn't working--not sure why.

Comment: @elyashiv I'm afraid I am a bid un-sophisticated when it comes to debugging, especially since I have to submit this code to a cluster and cannot really do much on the GPU until the job is finished. I crudely debug by commenting out code until I can isolate the issue, but once there I sometimes need to ask other. The only reason I posted ALL of this code is because I'm used to being yelled at for posting insufficient amounts of code.

Comment: You're not doing any proper [cuda error checking]().  Improper dereferencing of pointers in device code does not result in a seg fault (which is related to host code).  You should do proper cuda error checking, run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, and report the *actual* error output (whatever you are getting, instead of just referring to "seg fault".

Comment: Are these codes in two separate files?  If so please explain the file structure and give the exact commands you use to compile.  Also, you've been advised in the past that you are supposed to provide a SSCCE.org code, not just dump all of your code in a question.  I can't run your code even if I want to, since you haven't provided the input files.

Comment: You say that you using nothing in "support.h" at the moment, but when I try to compile your code, I get errors that things like "Timer" are undefined.  Voting to close.  You haven't provided a SSCCE.org code.  Your code as provided is not compilable by someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) you'll discover another problem with your code, this line:

```
cudaMemcpy(Times_d,Times_h,mat_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

should be something like this:

```
cudaMemcpy(Times_d,Times_h,vec_size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

However that's not the crux of the issue.  It took me a while to figure out that you are not making any kernel calls.  If you call a kernel, all the parameters you pass to that kernel must be accessible by the device. So if you pass a pointer, the pointer must point to device memory.  You are doing this with `mu_d` which is a device pointer:

```
calibrate(vec_size,mu_d,...
```

But your `calibrate` is not a kernel!!

It's an ordinary host function running on the host (CPU).  So when you try and dereference the device pointer `mu_d` in host code:

```
*mu = .11; // ERROR IS HERE!!
```

You get a seg fault.  I'm not sure why you're trying to debug this way, but simply converting kernel calls to host routines, while leaving all the parameters the same, is not a valid way to debug.

Fundamental CUDA rules (ignoring cuda 6 Unified Memory):

1. you cannot dereference a host pointer in device code
2. you cannot dereference a device pointer in host code

Your code is a violation of the 2nd rule above.